# How to databind a textbox to a DB field using LINQ to SQL, the right way?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, data-binding

Currently I'm writing an ASP.net webforms app, which works with a table containing 15 fields.
I'm using LINQ to SQL which is very good to use and everything, but when i need to bind the fields with the text boxes (15 of em), whats the best way currently I'm doing this

```
...
...
var stud = db.Students.SingleOrdefault(d => d.ApplicationNo == 32)
textbox1.Text = stud.Name;
...
...
```

I feel like I'm "missing the point". Please advise on the best way to do this.

- Also what should i do to implement
  the Move next and move previous
  functionality like a recordset

i mean how can i move to the next/previous "student" in db.Students collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind to an ASP.NET DetailsView control; this control supports displaying one record at a time, and can page through the results, so you don't have to do all that extra work.  You could also consider a FormView too, but you have to control that.

I think you have the right approach; you could also use ElementAt() to retrieve by an index; that can have some performance implications though.

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Skip and Take method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386988.aspx).

Update after comment:

You don't have to iterate through the different properties of the retrieved Student object. They're simply there. So you could use it like this:

```
txtName.Text = stud.Name;
txtAge.Text = stud.Age.ToString();
```

...

If you want to iterate to another record you can use the Skip and Take methods.

Grz, Kris.

Comment: I don't understand quite clearly. for eg: After i find a record based on a id such a ApplicationNo, how can i move next of that particular record ?